# strongly convex function and differentiable in $R^n$

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

> Be $f$ a strongly convex function and differentiable in $R^n$ and $\bar{x}$
> a solution of:
> $$\min f(x) \ \text{subject to}\ x\geq 0 $$.
> Show that exist $M > 0 $ such that for all $x \in R^n$:
> $$M\|x - \bar{x}\|^2 \leq (\langle x, \nabla f(x)\rangle)^2 + \sum(\max \{0,-(\nabla f(x))_i\})^2 + \sum(\max \{0, x_i\})$$

My attempt:
we now that for a strongly convex function, exist a $m>0$ such that: $$M \|x-y\|^2 \leq \langle\nabla f(x) -\nabla f(y), x-y \rangle$$
so, we replacement $y = \bar{x}$ and $\nabla f(\bar{x}) = 0$ because $\bar{x}$ is a solution of $\min f(x)$ so we have:
$$M \|x-y\|^2 \leq \langle \nabla f(x) , x-\bar{x} \rangle$$
and:
$$M \|x-y\|^2 \leq \langle \nabla f(x) , x-\bar{x} \rangle \leq \langle \nabla f(x) , x \rangle $$
and we now that: $\sum(\max \{0,-(\nabla f(x))_i\})^2 > 0$ and $\sum(\max \{0, x_i\}) > 0$
so we just say:
$$M \|x-y\|^2  \leq \langle \nabla f(x) , x \rangle \leq \langle \nabla f(x) , x \rangle ^2 +  \sum(\max \{0,-(\nabla f(x))_i\})^2 + \sum(\max \{0, x_i\})$$
hence:
$$M\|x - \bar{x}\|^2 \leq (\langle x, \nabla f(x)\rangle)^2 + \sum(\max \{0,-(\nabla f(x))_i\})^2 + \sum(\max \{0, x_i\})$$

Is this correct? if not, how can i solve this? Thanks.

Comment: You may use \langle and \rangle to produce $\langle$ and $\rangle$ instead of using < and >. You can use \mathbb{R} to get $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How do you take the $\max$ of a gradient?

Comment: @copper.hat sorry I just corrected it